# What is said about the temple?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

This questions comes about partially because it's hard for me to understand what's being said on-screen when there's lots of other action going on.

At one point in the film, there's a mention of the First Jedi Temple, and someone going there, to which Rey replies... *something unclear*.

I thought it sounded like a name, such as the name of the temple (not the planet), but I could not make it out.

**What was said when this subject was first brought up?**

Comment: Does the answer address what you are looking for or do you need additional info? Thx

Comment: @DVK I *think* it does, but I'm sort of hoping someone else can corroborate it. Are you going for some badge/hat that needs an accept at all?

Comment: not a badge. Far more important - rankings with Rand and Richard :) No pressure, if you feel a better answer is possible, let's see if one appears :)

Comment: @DVK Ah, but of course! Well, I'll probably wait a couple days, as more people see the film and hope for some votes/confirmation. It'll definitely be before the monthly total rep count rolls over ;)

Comment: Will not see a better answer you will, till more books Disney releases (IMHO).

Comment: @DVK But they released *The Visual Dictionary*, which may have something! The dialogue in the novelization is not identical to the movie. I have nothing against it, though, as Foster is usually pretty accurate. Also, I might actually just go see the movie again before the end of the year and take special note of the scene.

Comment: I intend to rewatch the film and adjust any novelization quotes I used to include film quotes which don't match. So far, none did.

Comment: @DVK Yes, please. Otherwise, if someone else does they may get the accept.

Comment: Done, Don Corleone. "Nice accept you have there, shame if something happened to it...."

Comment: All I know is that the first Jedi Temple is in the islands of Ireland.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From WGA script / Alan Dean Fosters TFA novelization: (blocks follow each other in that order, separated by a slash)

---

---

Han discussing where Luke went:

> **HAN**
>   There're a lot of rumors. Stories.
>   The people who knew him the best
>   think he went looking for the first Jedi temple.

/

> Han turned to him. “There’ve been all kinds of rumors and stories. When people don’t have access to facts, they invent what they’d like to believe, or what they think others would like to hear. The people who knew him the best think he went on a personal quest, looking for the first Jedi temple.”

---

---

Maz Kanata: (this piece was NOT in WGA script, just the novelization)

> “A map leading to the first Jedi temple!” Maz was marveling as she puttered about the kitchen. “To Skywalker himself! I’ve never given up hope for him.”

---

---

Admiral Statura discussing the map the First Order has: (this piece was NOT in WGA script, just the novelization)

> Admiral Statura nodded in agreement. “It makes sense. The Empire would have been looking for the first Jedi temples. In destroying all the Jedi sanctuaries they would have acquired a great deal of peripheral information.”

---

---

Then we see Rey's vision:

> She turns to look -- we PIVOT -- and see a **BURNING TEMPLE AT
>   NIGHT**. We PAN to:

/

> Day became night, sky ominous and filled with rain, cold and chilling to the bone. She was standing, she was sitting, she was looking up—to see someone, a warrior, take the full force of the lightsaber. He screamed and fell.
>   Battlefield then, all around her. Putting a hand to her mouth, she rose and turned. As she turned, she found herself confronted by seven tall, cloaked figures, dark and foreboding, all armed. Soaked and shivering, she stumbled backward, turning as she half fell. Firelight illuminated her, firelight from a distant, burning temple.

Comment: I'm so confused! I thought Leia and Rey talked about it. Not sure what I mixed up.

Comment: @CreationEdge  - do you mean once they get the full map out of R2?

Comment: I'm mixing up my timelines. It was probably around when Maz was there, but I could swear Rey said something. I'll rack my wife's brain tomorrow.

Comment: @CreationEdge - added. Rey said that the food was delicious. No Temple Talk while eating!

Answer (score 2):

I knew exactly what you were referring to as soon as I first saw this question, but I didn't know what the line was. When I saw the film again this past weekend, I had a friend listen for the line along with me, and he figured it out.

Aboard the Falcon, in the same scene where BB-8's map is first revealed, Han tells Rey that Luke disappeared while searching for "the first Jedi temple". For some reason, Rey's reply comes across as very indistinct to me. Some combination of Ridley's British accent, her delivery of that line, and the way it's recorded, I guess.

The first time seeing the film, I had no idea what she said, and the second time seeing it I could swear she said "The Jedi War (something)". My friend concurred, but after thinking it over for a minute, he realized she merely says "The Jedi were real?" quickly and excitedly.

And then Han proceeds with his affirmation that it's all real, the Jedi, etc.