# What Jedi Temple is Han talking about?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force-awakens

In Alan Dean Foster's novelization of *The Force Awakens*, Han Solo say this about Luke Skywalker:

> The people who knew him the best think he went on a personal quest, **looking for the first Jedi temple**

Is he talking about [the Jedi Temple on Coruscant](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Temple) (from the Prequels), or something else from EU/Legends stuff, or is it a completely new thing?

**What Temple is Han talking about?**

Comment: Even in the EU, the Coruscant temple was not the first Jedi temple.  The page you linked to even describes several other temples that existed before the Jedi arrived on Coruscant.

Comment: I figured that, but I don't think many non-Jedi would know that, so coming from Han, he might think the Coruscant one was the first one. When Han said that, I thought he _might_ be talking about the one on Coruscant and all I could think was __"they better not be referencing the prequels! No one wants to be reminded of those films"!__

Comment: I'm pretty sure hr days the same thing in the film.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was 100% most certainly NOT Coruscant. From the novelization, when Rey finds Luke:

> **The planet was mostly ocean, dotted with a sprinkling of towering islands formed of black rock: the throats of volcanoes whose slopes had long since eroded away**. Greenery caped the stony flanks, falling in emerald waves toward the azure sea. Above the calm waters, flying creatures soared on wide wings of translucent white.

Given that Coruscant is basically 100% covered in one large megalopolis, this is definitely a different planet.

The rest of the novelization [doesn't really say much about the Temple or the planet it's on](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111318/976).

Also... if it was Coruscant, I severely suspect **they wouldn't need a puzzle map to find the bloody capital of the Galactic Empire**, would they? :)

---

**UPDATE** According to WGA version of the script (confirmed as legit on Reddit), it's most certainly NOT Coruscant and called "AHCH-TO"

> EXT. **D'QAR - DAY**
>   The Millennium Falcon RISES.
>   Leia, with Poe, BB-8, and C-3PO (with his proper arm replaced), watches the next generation of Jedi begin her journey.
>   EXT. SPACE - DAY
>   The Falcon FLIES through space and BLASTS to LIGHTSPEED.
>   EXT. **AHCH-TO - DAY**
>   A pristine and mighty OCEAN. Endless BLUE, dotted with random, beautiful, mountainous BLACK ROCK ISLANDS, dotted with countless GREEN TREES.
>   The Millennium Falcon FLIES INTO VIEW, BANKS toward one of the ISLANDS.

---

In addition, curiously, we hear that there are many Jedi temples, which fits the EU:

> Admiral Statura nodded in agreement. “It makes sense. The Empire would have been looking for the first Jedi **temples**. In destroying all the Jedi sanctuaries they would have acquired a great deal of peripheral information.”

---

As far as EU, we have several worlds known to have Jedi Temples:

- [Tython](https://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tython)

  Unclear. I wouldn't say impossible, given Wiki description **of the original planet**. I wouldn't be surprised if it was the source of the ideas.

  However, by 0BBY, it wasn't a match: "the planet was covered by a constant layer of storms, and its surface was the color of ash, with barren plains where immense forests had once stood".
- [Ossus](https://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ossus/Legends)

  ... was ravaged into an arid and toxic planet when the wave struck the planet. Definitely doesn't fit "mostly ocean" (see [Wookieepedia picture](https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/2/2a/Ossus.jpg/revision/latest))
- [Taris](https://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Taris/Legends) was an ecumenopoly (city-world) like Coruscant. Unlikely.
- [Raxus Prime](https://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Raxus_Prime) was clearly NOT a sight of what could be even remotely called "First" Temple.

Comment: We know Luke went _looking_ for the first Jedi Temple.  Are we assuming he found it and that's the place we see at the end?

Comment: @RedCaio - yes. Because First Order also looked for it in Imperial archives, and they were searching for Luke.

Comment: I have this weird feeling that they're gonna end up saying that Luke's planet is Earth.

Comment: @mooz no doesn't fit description

Answer (score 4):

Han is referring to a new thing. It's a planet called [Ahch-To](https://www.slashfilm.com/star-wars-the-force-awakens-ending/) that was originally [in Imperial records](https://www.ew.com/article/2015/12/20/jj-abrams-answers-burning-question-about-r2-d2-star-wars-force-awakens):

> “We had the idea about R2 plugging into the information base of the Death Star, and that’s how he was able to get the full map and find where the Jedi temples are,” Arndt said.

After Luke found the map of all the Jedi Temples with the help of [Lor San Tekka](https://www.starwars.com/databank/lor-san-tekka), he left part of the map in the hands of the Lor San Tekka, who hands it off to Poe at the start of the film. Luke left the other part of the map in R2-D2.  The copy of the map later in Imperial records was partial, which is why Kylo Ren had a partial copy of the map as well.

This is why BB-8 was so important:

> he held the Lor San Tekka's piece of the map that others did not have.  After putting the map back together, the location is where Rey found Luke at the end of the film.

It's supposedly the first Jedi temple.

Comment: FYI: There was some unclearness if that's a name of the planet or an island. I think it's a planet but it's not 100% conclusive.

Comment: Oups never mind.... checked the script text - it's definitely a planet name based on location patterns

Comment: It is also confirmed by Pablo Hidalgo himself that it is the name of the planet.

Answer (score 2):

In Legends canon, one of the earliest known places inhabited by the beings who formed the [Je'daii Order](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Je%27daii_Order), which later became the Jedi, was [**Tython**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tython).  Many people are speculating that this is where Luke has gone in *SW:TFA*.

IIRC, in *SW:TFA*, Rey breathes the name of the First Temple when she hears that Luke has probably gone there.  But I did not catch what name she actually said.  And there does not seem to be any official mention of the temple's name elsewhere (yet?).

Comment: No she doesn't, at least in the novelization

Comment: I haven't read the novelization yet, but I just saw the film, and I'm pretty sure I heard her utter something when Han mentioned the temple, but I didn't catch what she said.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I saw the film again this weekend, and I could swear she said "The Jedi War (something)" - but a friend who saw it with me figured out after a minute that her line is "The Jedi were real?" The line was quite indistinct to me - she's speaking quickly and excitedly, so I guess it's hard for non-Brits to parse.